# Avoid using the WebBulder and use the Startup file

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've a .NET Core application that needs to peform operation based on a scheduler.
I've used the following code which also installs Kestrel but I don't need to use it at all

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var processModule = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            var assemblyName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName();
            var version = assemblyName.Version;

            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(processModule);

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var applicationName = configuration.GetValue<string>("Properties:Application");

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).Enrich.WithProperty("Version", version).Enrich
                .WithProperty("ApplicationName", applicationName)
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger = logger;

            Log.Logger.Information("Started {ApplicationName} with version : {Version}", applicationName, version);
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); }).UseSerilog()
                .UseWindowsService();
    }
```

And the Startup.cs is as follow :

```
class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            DataConnection.DefaultSettings = new Linq2DBSettings(configuration);
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
     //OMISS
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can have Startup.cs (or IServiceCollection ) so that I can initialize my DI in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all your services available in separate libraries, or you at least have the option to move them there from Web app, you could create some extension to configure DI both in your Web and Console applications

Library project

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection ApplyMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<MyService>();

            return services;
        }
    }

    public class MyService
    { }
}
```

Console app

```
using ClassLibrary;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            serviceCollection.ApplyMyServices();

            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var myService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Web app

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.ApplyMyServices();
}
```

Comment: Hello, in this case, I don't need at all to have the Kestrel part...so it's fine to have it how you told me?

Comment: @advapi it is up to you to decide whether my code matches your expectations, but I like this approach for its reusability

Comment: you probably will need to move your appsettings.json as well to make sure every project has access to it

Comment: excuse me, but how do you set this ServiceCollection to be the one of the application... I mean using the Host.CreateBuilder is somehow tells the app which IServiceCollection I've to use... I don't see it here

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. I create service collection with `new ServiceCollection()`

Comment: the same way host builder creates service collection and uses it in asp.net core pipeline